# Error when using multiple character in Python csv module

Tags: python, csv

I'm  getting this:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';;')
```

`delimiter` must be an 1-character string

is it possible to make it work with two characters?

Comment: Roll your own by reading as an ordinary file and row.split(";;")

Comment: @CurlyJoe That's easily broken with valid csv like `5;;"hello;;there"` which should have two elements as csv, but will have three with yours.

Comment: Huh??  It would have to be a mistake when writing the csv file as there is no valid syntax like "hello;;there".  And generally a delimiter should be  chosen so that it won't occur naturally and mistakes like this can be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do it with the csv module, you could do update the file and replace the `;;` with tabs or some common delimiter or you could use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=";;")
print(df.A)
print(df.B)
print(df.C)
```

test.csv:

```
A;;B;;C
1;;2;;3
4;;5;;6
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
0    2
1    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
0    3
1    6
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

To get rows:

```
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.values)
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
```